# how to get successfull payments or transaction from stripe using laravel cashier

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

how to get successful payments or transactions against the particular user from stripe using laravel cashier. I google it but still, I am not able to find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a native way to do this in Cashier that I'm not aware of the way to do this against the API is to list PaymentIntents (or Charges) and filter by the Customer, for example:

```
$payment_intents = $stripe->paymentIntents->all(['customer' => 'cus_xxx']);
```

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list?lang=php#list_payment_intents-customer

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=php#list_charges-customer

Comment: thanks for your precious time and help.your reply help me a lot in solving my problem